# Question regarding Roll Pitch Yaw and coordinate system

Tags: ros, coordinate-system, yaw, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all !

I have a question regarding the Roll Pitch Yaw convention in ROS (applying to all the the  getRPY and quaternion convertion function).

I am aware that the convention in ROS is the fixed XYZ transform based on this [post].(http://answers.ros.org/question/58863/incorrect-rollpitch-yaw-values-using-getrpy/)

But what happens if the two coordinate systems used are not the same. Does the same Roll Pitch Yaw can be applied on both to express orientation ?

In my application my sensor is in NED and returns me the Roll Pitch Yaw. Can I apply this directly into ROS and use it in the quaternion convertion, to make a odometry message or to use it in a TF since ROS is in ENU ?

Thanks again !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71488/question-regarding-roll-pitch-yaw-and-coordinate-system/) by [ETS-Dronolab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4112/ets-dronolab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions#Ground_reference_frames:_ENU_and_NED) answers your question.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ETS-Dronolab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4112/ets-dronolab/) on 2013-08-06**:
Well, it's illustrate better what I thought. There is an ambiguity with the Euler angles convertion and utilization in ROS. There should be function to convert Roll Pitch Yaw from other axis convention to ENU Euler angles.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The names roll pitch and yaw have different meanings in different contexts.  You need to understand the ones you are receiving and correctly input them with the syntax expected by the API. For clarity we have changed to fixed axis representation to avoid the many variations of euler angles.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1